# Card dealing mathematics problem

Tags: cyclic-orders

I have found the following card trick:

- Take a stack of **n** cards, with a known order.
- Deal the cards from your hand onto the table like this: Card from the top, then card from the bottom, from the top, from the bottom, etc until the deck is depleted.
- Keep dealing the cards like this. After a certain amount of deals (lets call that **d**) the original order will be restored.

I have made a table for n=1 through 25. The numbers for d are, consecutively:
`1,2,2,3,3,5,6,4,4,9,6,11,10,9,14,5,5,12,18,12,10,7,12,23,21`
I'm trying to find a pattern here, but I can't find one. My first thought was that after the same amount of deals as the amount of cards the sequence would repeat. Some seem to conform to n-1=d, but most don't. If you check for n-1=z*d, where z is an integer, most of them conform, but some don't.

Does anyone know what logic is hidden here? What is so special about n=16 and 17 (both just 5 deals required) and n=22 (just 7 deals required)?

Comment: From your table, there is a conjecture: with $2^n$ or $2^n+1$ cards, you get period $n+1$. But please specify your algorithm. The topmost card ends up topmost in the new pile, or at the bottom? For three cards 1-2-3 gives 2-3-1 or 1-3-2? According to your table, it should be 1-3-2.

Comment: It's probably this one: http://oeis.org/A216066

Answer (score 4):

In mathematical language, you're talking about the order of a certain permutation on $n$ letters, which can be easily computed using the cycle structure of the permutation.

Your sequence is [OEIS sequence A216066](https://oeis.org/A216066), except that you have 1,2,2,3,... instead of 1,1,2,3,....  See in particular Robert Pfister's comment.